# Каков список литература для C1?

Tags: русская-графика

Здравствуйте!

Для подбора аргументов нужно знать много литературных произведений. Думаю, весомую часть часть я и так прочитал, но хотел бы освежить знания. Напишите, пожалуйста, список литературных произведений, которые нужно прочитать по школьному курсы или околошкольному, из которых можно приводить аргументы в сочинение по русскому языку.

Спасибо.

PS Я понимаю, что список большой, но думаю многим будете полезен. Напишите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Можно приводить из всех, что вы читали.
Главное - чтобы языка была русская, великая и могучая.

Comment: Что над юношей издеваетесь-то, у Вас еще не такие опечатки бывают!

Comment: Ларf, так я не против, когда над моими опечатками тонко и умно издеваются.  
Но тут я про образ мысли. "Выложите мне все аргументы, которые я имею право приводить". Вот же что забавляет. Это ЕГЭ так людей закрепощает или вообще "О tempora, о mores"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам программу по литературе за 8-11 классы сюда переписать? И список внеклассного чтения? Иногда приходится вспоминать произведения младших классов, например, "Зелёную лампу" на тему значения одиночества в жизни человека, "Кладовую солнца" и т.д. Всё, что Вы знаете, пригодится. Если много читали, эпизод вспомнится и без перечитывания, если мало - прочитайте то, что не удосужились прочитать. Вообще, знания не бывают лишними. Не сейчас - потом пригодится. А вот если не прочитано даже положенное, бывает, боком выходит:попадётся именно это. А темы сейчас интересные пошли, трудно предвидеть, о чём будет текст: о научном прогрессе, о чувстве ответственности("Собачье сердце" и "Роковые яйца" Булгакова), о языке, о чести и совести("Капитанская дочка"), о случае и закономерности (Лермонтов "Фаталист"), о материнской любви, о нравственном выборе("В.Быков "Сотников").Сколько ещё перечислять? Места не хватит.

Comment: Если можно, просто список внеклассного чтения.

Comment: Вот хотя бы: http://samschool96.ucoz.ru/index/spisok_proizvedenij_dlja_chtenija_letom_9_11_klassy/0-43

Comment: @Людмила, Вы чуть чуть меня не поняли. Я просил не список литературы + аргумент, а просто название произведений, которые входят в школьный курс + внеклассное чтение. Спасибо.

Comment: А по ссылке как раз список произведений для изучения в 9-11 классе. Никаких там аргументов нет.

Comment: @Ларf, я понял. Просто надо было сразу эту ссылку и дать. Я это и искал. Просто попытался объясниться.  Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Пройдя по ссылке, Вы найдете не только готовые аргументы для тех, кто не хочет думать сам и ничего не читал, но и список литературы для тех, кто хочет серьезно подготовиться к экзамену. Читайте классику! В "Войне и мире", например, Вы найдете аргументы-иллюстрации ко многим проблемам, поднимаемым в экзаменационных текстах.

[link text](http://5-ege.ru/argumenty-k-sochineniyu/)